# Can't change Console.Title on VS2019 C#

Tags: c#, console-application

Just starting with **C#** and I'm trying to do very simple things, one of these is changing the  **console title**.

I'm following these instructions: [Console.Title Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.title?view=netcore-3.1#examples)

The link above is from the **Microsoft documentation**, and when I copy it in my program it works!

When I try to do the same thing, even simpler... well the title doesn't change at all.

---

*My code:*

```
using System;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "Hello World Program";
        }
    }
}
```

---

*My output:*

[image]

What am I doing wrong? There is some extra step that I must take which I'm not aware of?

---

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: if you execute the .exe in the bin folder, try to delete it and re-generate it. if you verify in debug mode will work well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After your program exits, Console will no longer have the title you set it to. Use a breakpoint at the end to see what the title is before your program exits.

```
Console.Title = "New";
return; // Set a breakpoint here.
```

or you can simply add a 'press any key to continue' (as per the MS docs)

```
Console.WriteLine("Note that the new console title is \"{0}\"\n" +
                      "  (Press any key to quit.)", Console.Title);
Console.ReadKey(true);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So basically the title will stay as long as the application is running...